# HTML5 and CSS3 is messing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to make a blog website using Django. While I was doing the front-end stuff I ran into this issue. The code is given below,
the problem with it is shown in the image linked to this post The header is consuming so much free space. Meanwhile, I made a similar page with almost the exact same code (both HTML and CSS) files.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}


/*Global*/

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.highlight {
  color: #f64003;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background-color: #1f1e1e;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 3px #f64003 solid;
  max-height: 20%;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

header .logoTextArea {
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0;
}

header .logoTextArea h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

header .navigation .left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header .navigation .left ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}

header .navigation a:hover {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #f64003;
}

header .navigation .right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header .navigation .right ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* ShowCase Area */

.showcase {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url('./images/mainBG.jpeg') no-repeat -150px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px #f64003 solid;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> {% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blogs/posts.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='logoTextArea'>
        <h1>BRE<span class="highlight">V</span>ITY BL<span class='highlight'>O</span>GS</h1>
      </div>
      <div class='navigation'>
        <nav class='left'>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href='/'>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='news.html'>News</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class='right'>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href='login.html'>Log In!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href='https://patreon.com/Brevity'>Become a patreon!</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h1>Scroll <span class="highlight">Down</span> for Blogs</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="blogs">
      <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}

        <li><a class="Bpost" href="/details/{{post.id}}"> {{post.title}} <br> {{post.created_at}} </a> </li>

        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code you pasted renders differently compared to the screenshot. Make sure you provide the exact snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, you have the header set to 50% of the screen [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

```
header .logoTextArea {
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Remove or reduce the height value to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! If you could accept my answer that would be great, thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Lot of things to change :) View in full page.

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
}

/*Global*/

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.highlight{
    color: #f64003;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Header */
header{
    background-color: #1f1e1e;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3px #f64003 solid;
    max-height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

header ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

header .logoTextArea{
    height: 1%;
    width: 1%;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

header .logoTextArea h1{
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .navigation .left{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header .navigation .left ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
}

header .navigation a:hover{
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #f64003;
}

header .navigation .right{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    /*padding: 0 20px 0 20px;*/
}

header .navigation .right ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    /*margin: 10px;*/
}

/* ShowCase Area */

.showcase{
 min-height: 500px;
 background: url('./images/mainBG.jpeg') no-repeat -150px 0;
 border-bottom: 2px #f64003 solid;
}
.showcase h1{
 font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blogs/posts.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='logoTextArea'>
                <h1>BRE<span class="highlight">V</span>ITY BL<span class='highlight'>O</span>GS</h1>
            </div>
            <div class='navigation'>
                <nav class='left'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href='/'>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='news.html'>News</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav class='right'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href='login.html'>Log In!</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href='https://patreon.com/Brevity'>Become a patreon!</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Scroll <span class="highlight">Down</span> for Blogs</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="blogs">
            <ul>
                {% for post in posts %}
                
                <li><a class="Bpost" href="/details/{{post.id}}"> {{post.title}} <br> {{post.created_at}} </a> </li>

                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```